# llvm gcc 4.2 error: setting a C++ non-POD object value is not implemented

Tags: llvm, xcode4.2

I'm getting this error in code that used to compile (it's been some time since I last removed Xcode3.2.5 and install Xcode4.2, but it has worked well with Xcode3.2.5 before).

xxx.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string address;
```

xxx.mm

```
TalkListController *controller = [[TalkListController alloc] init];    
controller.address = self.address;           <----------wrong line
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
[controller setAddress:self.address];
```